# tableau server 500 error

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, tableau-api

I was getting an Tableau server error(500) when trying to open workbook in Tableau server:"Data source exception:[Hortonworks]Hardy Error from server code: '0' error message: ExecuteStatement finished with operation state".

However, no error found when opening the workbook with Tableau Desktop.

Any idea on this error?

Answer (score 0):

This error is most commonly encountered when a Tableau Desktop user publishes a workbook that uses a data source that is local to their computer or is otherwise inaccessible by Tableau Server.

Make sure your server run as account has access to the data source your are trying to connect to.